# armv8 64 bit architecture support in clang

Tags: xcode, clang, 64-bit, arm64, armv7

I'm trying to use clang to cross compile to 64 bit armv8. My clang version info is the following.

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

The following work

```
clang -arch armv7
clang -arch arm64
```

But I have not been able to find how to build for armv8 64 bit, or even if it is supported.

If it is supported, how do I build for it?
If it is not supported, what is the best approximation within clang?

Thanks!
  Damon

Comment: In clang, "-arch arm64" means "ARMv8 AArch64"

Comment: @VariableLengthCoder: make that an answer.

Answer (score 10):

In clang, `-arch arm64` means `ARMv8 AArch64`.  That is, the 64-bit version of the ARMv8 instruction set architecture.

Comment: I know you are right, but can you list your sources. I'm just really tired of the obscurity behind xcode's target architectures.

Answer (score 0):

- `ARMv8` already/is `64bit`

  - `arm64` ~= `ARMv8` ~= `AArch64`
- on Mac, using `clang` to build for arm64:

  - `clang -arch arm64 main.c -o main_arm64`